# GET XMLHttpRequest stops at readystate 4 and status 0

Tags: javascript, api, get, xmlhttprequest

I've been trying to get article from NewsAPI.org but I got this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=general&apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXX' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

And I noticed it stops at readystate 4 and status 0.

this is the code of the function I use:

```
function getNews()
{
    var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country='+country+'&category='+category+'&apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET' , url);
    req.send();

    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)   
            {
                news = JSON.parse(req.response);
                news = news.articles;
                displayNews();
            }
    }
}
```

Note: I tried to add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header but it makes no change.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the xhr request is not stopping at `req.readystate == 4` instead at `res.send()`. Also `CORS` is a standard web security service provided by the browser to prevent data leak from other origin.

For testing locally, you can bypass it by adding the header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```